# Integration app into License Verification Library (LVL) sample code

Tags: android, android-lvl

After reading a bunch of articles and tutorials about how to make an Android app, I've managed to create one simple application that I wanted to upload to Google Play marketplace, then I encountered new term for me - License Verification Library (LVL), which for me was a total nightmare to understand, but somehow I managed to run a sample code which I got downloaded from the internet.

Interesting situation - I have my own app without integrated LVL which works perfectly fine in the virtual environment; on other hand, I have a working sample app with integrated LVL.

The problem is that I don't understand how to integrate LVL into my own application.

The questions are:

- Do I have to integrate my app into LVL sample code or LVL into my application code?
- Which is easier and better practice?
- Are there any examples that show where to implement code to make it work correctly with LVL?

Any diagrams would help...